# How to run Cypress test runner in vagrant guest using host machine's browser in Ubuntu

Tags: vagrant, cypress

I have a project in a vagrant box i'd like to run e2e tests on with cypress. I am able to run cypress headless within the guest machine. But I'd like the GUI features that it offers. How can I run Cypress so that it can use the host's browser to run the tests?
I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what to do, just in case anyone else in the future needs to do this.

Apparently for this to work, there's need for `X-forwarding`. That means the guest must forward the GUI display to the host.

Assuming you have correctly installed cypress and can run it headless: `yarn run cypress run` (or whichever way you run it, `npm` etc)

**1. You need an X-Server on the host.**

- On Linux, you already have and X Server running
- On Mac, On Mac OSX you can install XQuartz

**2. Enable X-forwarding on your Vagrant VM**

Just add this to your `Vagrantfile`

```
config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
```

**3. Ssh into the box without vagrant ssh**

We need to access the guest with `ssh` as opposed to the normal `vagrant ssh`. Do do this:
run `vagrant ssh-config` on the host in your directory with the vagrant file

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User ubuntu
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/xxxx/work/.vagrant/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardX11 yes
```

From this we have the details we need to ssh. The `user`, the `HostName` the `Port` and the `IdentityFile`.

Now we can, from the host `ssh` into the guest and run the cypress test runner.

We also need to add `-X` flag that tells ssh to use the X-forwarding.

Assuming my project runs in a directory called project in the home directory of my guest machine... Run this command from the host machine while your box in running.

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -X -p 2222 -i /Users/xxxx/work/.vagrant/private_key -t "cd /home/vagrant/project; yarn run cypress open"
```

Voila! the Test runner will run in your box and the GUI will display on your host machine.

Credits to [Gabor](https://code-maven.com/xforwarding-from-vagrant-box) and [Martin](https://coderwall.com/p/ozhfva/run-graphical-programs-within-vagrantboxes)

Comment: Great instructions, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a Linux Host, you really just need to map a volume from `/tmp/.X11-unix` on the host through to the guest.

```
d.volumes = ["/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix"]
```

ref: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant_docker_cypress/blob/main/Vagrantfile#L38

A full example is located here: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant_docker_cypress
and a video showing it working:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDmNgtyE_kE